# Find the vectorial equation of the line through $P$ and orthogonal to two planes

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I have to find the vectorial equation of the line through $P$ and orthogonal to $r:(x,y,z)=(1,−1,−1)+\lambda(1,−1,0)$ and $s:(x,y,z)=(\frac{3}{2},-\frac{1}{2},0)+\alpha(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1)$.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** one direction orthogonal to both lines is the vector ${\bf v} = (1,-1,1)\times\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1\right)$. Then your line is ${\bf X}(t) = P+t{\bf v},$ with $t \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: so, supposing $P=(3,2,1)$ it would be $X(t)=(3,2,1)+t(-1,-1,1)$?

Comment: Yes, just plug in everything, there is no difficulty there. The point of the exercise was only noticing that the direction orthogonal to both lines is given by the cross product.